# Why is list changing with no reason?

Tags: python

I passed the copy of a list to a function and for some reason the original list changed.I tried everything I could and this is totally illogical or I did something really wrong.

```
maze="""XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXX            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX EXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXX          XXXX     XXX
XX XX           XXX XXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXX
XX XX XXXXXXXXX XX  XXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXX
XX XX XXXXXXX XXXXX XXXXXXX XXXX XXXXXXX
XX XX XXXX    XXXXX XXXXX             XX
XX XX XXXX XX XXXXX   XXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XX XX XXXX XX XXXXXXX XXX     XXXX    XX
XX XX      XX     XXX XXXXXXX XXXX XX XX
XX XXXXXXXXXX XXX XXX XXXXXXX      XXXXX
XX      XXXXX XXX XXXXXX      XXXX XXXXX
XXXX XX XXXXX XXX XX     XXXX XXXX   XXX
XXXX XX XXXXX XXX XX XXXXXXXX XXXXXX XXX
XX   XX XXX   XXX XX XXXXX      XXXX XXX
XXXX XX     XXXXX    XXXXX XXXXXXX XXXXX
XXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX   XXX
XXXX                XXX        XXXXX XXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXX XXX
XXX              XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXX XXX
XXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   XX     XXXXX  XX
XXX             XX XX XXXX XXXXXXXXXX XX
XS  XXXXXXXX XXXXX    XXXX            XX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"""
grid=maze.split("\n")
for x in xrange(len(grid)):
    grid[x]=list(grid[x])
row=len(grid)
col=len(grid[0])
def check(maze,x,z,row,col):
    lim=0
    if z+1<col and maze[x][z+1]=="X":
        lim+=1
    if x+1<row and maze[x+1][z]=="X":
        lim+=1
    if z-1>=0 and maze[x][z-1]=="X":
        lim+=1
    if x-1>=0 and maze[x-1][z]=="X":
        lim+=1
    return lim
def get_pos(grida,row,col):
    for l in xrange(100):
        for x in xrange(len(grida)):
            for z in xrange(len(grida[x])):
                if check(grida,x,z,row,col)>=3 and grida[x][z]!="E" and grida[x][z]!="S":
                    grida[x][z]="X"
                else:
                    continue
    return grida
grid_temp=grid[:]
print grid
grid_2=get_pos(grid_temp,row,col)
print grid
```

I want to know why grid is actually changing.

Comment: Is it? Asking a question that starts with "Why" is not a good idea. First make sure, that the list actually *is* changing *with no reason*.

Comment: @LutzHorn You see I want to know the reason if there really is one.I can't seem to find it.
grid_temp=grid[:]
print grid
grid_2=get_pos(grid_temp,row,col)
print grid

It just changes after that function which has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your grid variable is a 2D array, i.e. a list of lists. When you do `grid[:]` you are making a new list of lists, but the elements themselves are still references to the same maze row. You want to do a deepcopy, e.g. the `deepcopy` function from the `copy` module.

Comment: duh shorter answers are faster to write, eh? :P

Comment: Thanks a lot mate.This works perfect.Well I think I still have a lot to learn but I never knew that so thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution, use `copy` module instead of ad hoc copying:

```
import copy
foo = copy.deepcopy(bar)
```

To answer your question, I think *why* comes down to following bit in your code:

```
grida[x][y] = ...
```

While your `[:]` copy only copies one level deep, the assignment is two levels deep.

Comment: Thanks but I tried [:][:] as I remember.It still did not work.Anyways thanks for this as well :p

Comment: [:][:] is copying one level deep two times

Answer (score 0):

You, my friend, are having trouble with **namespaces.**
Try new_array = old_array[:].
This causes a slice in the array, but because there aren't any numbers before or after the colon, it's not cutting anything off, but still forcing a duplicate of the array.

## Naming and binding

*Names* refer to objects.  Names are introduced by name binding
operations. Each occurrence of a name in the program text refers to
the *binding* of that name established in the innermost function block
containing the use.

A *block* is a piece of Python program text that is executed as a
unit. The following are blocks: a module, a function body, and a class
definition. Each command typed interactively is a block.  A script
file (a file given as standard input to the interpreter or specified
as a command line argument to the interpreter) is a code block.  A
script command (a command specified on the interpreter command line
with the '**-c**' option) is a code block.  The string argument passed
to the built-in functions "eval()" and "exec()" is a code block.

A code block is executed in an *execution frame*.  A frame contains
some administrative information (used for debugging) and determines
where and how execution continues after the code block's execution has
completed.

A *scope* defines the visibility of a name within a block.  If a local
variable is defined in a block, its scope includes that block.  If the
definition occurs in a function block, the scope extends to any blocks
contained within the defining one, unless a contained block introduces
a different binding for the name.  The scope of names defined in a
class block is limited to the class block; it does not extend to the
code blocks of methods -- this includes comprehensions and generator
expressions since they are implemented using a function scope.  This
means that the following will fail:

class A:
       a = 42
       b = list(a + i for i in range(10))

When a name is used in a code block, it is resolved using the nearest
enclosing scope.  The set of all such scopes visible to a code block
is called the block's *environment*.

If a name is bound in a block, it is a local variable of that block,
unless declared as "nonlocal".  If a name is bound at the module
level, it is a global variable.  (The variables of the module code
block are local and global.)  If a variable is used in a code block
but not defined there, it is a *free variable*.

When a name is not found at all, a "NameError" exception is raised.
If the name refers to a local variable that has not been bound, an
"UnboundLocalError" exception is raised.  "UnboundLocalError" is a
subclass of "NameError".

The following constructs bind names: formal parameters to functions,
"import" statements, class and function definitions (these bind the
class or function name in the defining block), and targets that are
identifiers if occurring in an assignment, "for" loop header, or after
"as" in a "with" statement or "except" clause. The "import" statement
of the form "from ... import *" binds all names defined in the
imported module, except those beginning with an underscore.  This form
may only be used at the module level.

A target occurring in a "del" statement is also considered bound for
this purpose (though the actual semantics are to unbind the name).

Each assignment or import statement occurs within a block defined by a
class or function definition or at the module level (the top-level
code block).

If a name binding operation occurs anywhere within a code block, all
uses of the name within the block are treated as references to the
current block.  This can lead to errors when a name is used within a
block before it is bound.  This rule is subtle.  Python lacks
declarations and allows name binding operations to occur anywhere
within a code block.  The local variables of a code block can be
determined by scanning the entire text of the block for name binding
operations.

If the "global" statement occurs within a block, all uses of the name
specified in the statement refer to the binding of that name in the
top-level namespace.  Names are resolved in the top-level namespace by
searching the global namespace, i.e. the namespace of the module
containing the code block, and the builtins namespace, the namespace
of the module "builtins".  The global namespace is searched first.  If
the name is not found there, the builtins namespace is searched.  The
global statement must precede all uses of the name.

The builtins namespace associated with the execution of a code block
is actually found by looking up the name "**builtins**" in its global
namespace; this should be a dictionary or a module (in the latter case
the module's dictionary is used).  By default, when in the "**main**"
module, "**builtins**" is the built-in module "builtins"; when in any
other module, "**builtins**" is an alias for the dictionary of the
"builtins" module itself.  "**builtins**" can be set to a user-created
dictionary to create a weak form of restricted execution.

**CPython implementation detail:** Users should not touch
"**builtins**"; it is strictly an implementation detail.  Users
wanting to override values in the builtins namespace should "import"
the "builtins" module and modify its attributes appropriately.

The namespace for a module is automatically created the first time a
module is imported.  The main module for a script is always called
"**main**".

The "global" statement has the same scope as a name binding operation
in the same block.  If the nearest enclosing scope for a free variable
contains a global statement, the free variable is treated as a global.

A class definition is an executable statement that may use and define
names. These references follow the normal rules for name resolution.
The namespace of the class definition becomes the attribute dictionary
of the class.  Names defined at the class scope are not visible in
methods.

Interaction with dynamic features

---

There are several cases where Python statements are illegal when used
in conjunction with nested scopes that contain free variables.

If a variable is referenced in an enclosing scope, it is illegal to
delete the name.  An error will be reported at compile time.

If the wild card form of import --- "import *" --- is used in a
function and the function contains or is a nested block with free
variables, the compiler will raise a "SyntaxError".

The "eval()" and "exec()" functions do not have access to the full
environment for resolving names.  Names may be resolved in the local
and global namespaces of the caller.  Free variables are not resolved
in the nearest enclosing namespace, but in the global namespace.  [1]
The "exec()" and "eval()" functions have optional arguments to
override the global and local namespace.  If only one namespace is
specified, it is used for both.

Related help topics: global, nonlocal, ASSIGNMENT, DELETION,DYNAMICFEATURES